# Python converting - [<Location: London>] to London

Tags: python, django

Excuse my total newbie question but how do I convert:

`[<Location: London>]` or `[<Location: Edinburgh>, <Location: London>]`  etc

into:

'London' or 'Edinburgh, london'

Some background info to put it in context:

Models.py:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.place

class LocationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
```

forms.py

```
class BookingForm(forms.Form):  
    place = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all(), label='Venue/Location:', required=False)
```

views.py

```
def booking(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
                place = form.cleaned_data['place'] 
                recipients.append(sender)
                message = '\nVenue or Location: ' + str(place)
                send_mail('Thank you for booking', message, sender, recipients)
)
```

Comment: Is that a string or did you print a dictionary?

Comment: Looks like you're viewing the __unicode__ representation of your model. Show us the model code and we can explain which field to access and how to do it

Comment: Are you talking about a list of strings or a list of `Location` model class instances here? If it is a list of model instances, try `map(str, <list>)`

Comment: -1: Not enough code to even guess what's going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're printing the QueryList instead of the individual elements.

```
u', '.join(x.place for x in Q)
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the `__repr__` method if you want to change the way a Django model is printed in the shell.

Comment: That won't change how the QueryList is displayed though.

Comment: The original question has been changed since I posted this answer. What's the recommended policy on that? Delete the answer? Leave it?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a result from a query you're printing there, try

```
[x.name for x in result]
```

if `name` is the attribute containing the location's name.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a regexp. Given your first example :

```
import re
s = "[<Location: London>]"
m = re.search("Location: (.*)>", s)
print m.group(1)
London
```